# Confused about how set in python returns values

Tags: python, list, set

I have a code.

```
scores = [19.0,19.0,20.0,20.0,21.0,21.0]
new_scores = set(scores)
print new_scores
```

Output:
set([19.0, 20.0, 21.0])

My Question:
Why is the word 'set' prefixed to the output.
Isn't set supposed to return directly the unique values in the list 'scores'. Also, if i use 'list(set(scores))' then i get the intended output of only the list of unique values without the prefix word 'set'

Comment: `Why is the word 'set' prefixed to the output. ` Why not? You should ask the person who wrote the `__str__` method for `set`.

Comment: `set` makes a set, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set` is a type in Python. When you do:

```
set(some_list)
```

you don't get a list back, you get a `set`. A `set` in Python is not the same as a `list` and has it's own interface. For instance, you cannot `append` to a `set`. You can only `add`.

```
>>> my_set = set(['a', 'b'])
>>> my_set.append('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> my_set.add('a')
>>> print(my_set)
{'a', 'b'}
```

Notice, when I `add` to the set, I still only have 'a', since it's **behaving** like a set.

However:

```
list(set(['a']))
```

it is now a list. Which no longer behaves like a set, thus:

```
>>> my_list = list(set(['a']))
>>> my_list.append('a')
>>> print(my_list)
['a', 'a']
```

notice that the structure **behaves** like a `list`.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!